# Android - How does dp occupy different space in devices with different sizes?

Tags: android, pixel, dpi, screen-size, screen-density

I searched a lot about dp, px, inch, pt etc.

From what I understood about 'dp':

Specifying 'dp' is simply a way to make Android draw the views with same size for devices with different screen densities. Eg, for a medium density device, each 'dp' will occupy a pixel. For a high density device - which has smaller pixels to fit more pixels per inch, 'dp' will occupy more than a pixel. For a low density device - which has larger pixels to fit less pixels per inch, 'dp' will occupy  less than a pixel.

But what I also read is that space occupied by a 'dp'  varies according to screen sizes, i.e for a small screen a 'dp' will occupy less space, while for a larger screen a 'dp' will occupy larger space.
How exactly does this happen? From what I understood about 'dp', it should occupy the same amount of space in devices with differing screen sizes. Eg, a large screen of 240 dpi will have a 'dp' occupy 1.5 pixels, and so will be the case for a small screen of 240 dpi. Then how is it that a 'dp' will occupy different amount of space for different screen sizes?

What am I missing in my understanding of 'dp'? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android defines a baseline dpi of **160** which is used as the **reference** to compute sizes for all screen densities:

```
pixel_size * (device_dpi / baseline_dpi) = result in "dp" units

>> or the other way around 

dp_size / (device_dpi / baseline_dpi) = result in "pixel" units
```

Therefore, 1 pixel in a 240dpi device is equivalent to 1.5dp units:

```
1 * (240 / 160) = 1.5
```

and the other way around, 1.5dp units in a 240dpi device is equivalent to 1 pixel

```
1.5 / (240 / 160) = 1
```

The important fact to know is that **160** is the baseline used as the **reference** for all DPIs.
So, as dp units increase/decrease, the required pixels area to draw something translates into keeping the same size scale regardless of the device screen.

More information in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

**To be more clear:**

The display size is not related to "dp units". The display size is just how big the display canvas is. The screen DPI defines how many dots fit in 1 square inch. And a "dp unit" is an abstract unit that, depending on the device's DPI, is scaled (up or down) to give "uniform dimensions" on any screen size, by using 160 as the baseline reference.

Comment: I understand the relation between screen density and dp, but don't seem to understand the relation between screen physical size and dp. Please elaborate.

Comment: there is no relation to screen size.. dont get confused with it..

Comment: The display size is not related to "dp units". The display size is just how big the display canvas is. To understand everything you need to focus in the fact that the screen DPI defines how many dots fit in 1 square inch, and, that a "dp unit" is an abstract unit that, depending on the device's DPI, is scaled (up or down) to give "uniform dimensions" on any screen size, by using 160 as the baseline reference.

Comment: @PerracoLabs I think the formula mentioned by you is mistaken, as the docs say:
`px = dp * (dpi / 160)`. Link: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#dips-pels

Answer (score 0):

on the Android operating system a device-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen. By this definition, you can understanddp has no relation with screen sizes as the scale is already fixed as 160 dpi.

.

Comment: You mean 'dp' occupies the same size whether it is small or large device, if they both have same screen density?

Comment: yes, even with different or same screen densities or sizes dp is same everywhere as it is density-independent pixels. Actual pixels are calculated by android based on actual screen densities. developers change dp sizes on different screens because on say larger devices, u mght want more margins, paddings and smallers margins,padding on smaller devices.